# What does *ptr2 = ptr mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently working on a doubly linked list for one of my classes. One of our stress tests looks like this:

```
//Delcarations
DLList<string> list;
DLList<string>* list2;

list.clear();                         //Clears the list
list2 = &list;                        //Sets the values to be the same
list.addHead("I'm meant to be here"); //Adds this as head of both lists
*list2 = list;                        //Unsure what this does
printFunc(*list2);                    //prints the contents of the list
```

My output box just shows both `list` and `list2` become `NULL`, and when I print `*list2` it prints `NULL`.

My questions are:

1. What is `*list2 = list` actually doing?
2. Why are my values just both becoming NULL?

Comment: `*list2 = list` is lvalue reference in C++: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/

Comment: @JaMiT I'm sorry, I edited my post to include the declarations. And yes, that is intentional.

Comment: @JaMiT Again, I'm sorry. I didn't catch that.

Comment: The answer depends entirely on what a `DLList<T>` is.

Comment: Let's see, `list2 = &list;` sets the address held by the pointer `list2` to `list` (`list2` now points to `list`). Then `*list2 = list;` attempts to set the value at the address held by `list2` to `list`. And since `list2` already holds the address of `list`, `*list2 = list;` is equivalent to `list = list;` (and @selbie is correct -- whether that holds will depend on what `DLList<T>` is...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two of your comments are incorrect. Perhaps corrected comments would make the situation clearer? (I'm going to assume that function names are indicative of what they are intended to do, even though such assumptions are not always accurate.)

> ```
> list2 = &list;                        //Sets the values to be the same
> ```

No, this causes `list2` to point to the list you just cleared. There is only one list, only one set of values in the list.

> ```
> list.addHead("I'm meant to be here"); //Adds this as head of both lists
> ```

No, there is only one list. This adds "I'm meant to be here" to the head of *the* list.

> ```
> *list2 = list;                        //Unsure what this does
> ```

This takes the list to which `list2` points (a.k.a. `list` as of two lines earlier) and replaces its contents with the contents of `list`. That is, it performs self-assignment in a fashion that might go undetected by a compiler, hence might avoid being optimized away. (It also might go undetected by the student trying to pass the stress test. ;) ) Logically, though, this line is functionally the same as `list = list;`.

> ```
> printFunc(*list2);                    //prints the contents of the list
> ```

This prints null? That suggests your assignment operator does not correctly handle self-assignment.

Comment: You're most likely correct. I've only be using pointers for about 4-5 weeks now so I'm not completely used to how they function. I've had a lot of problems with my assignment operator, so that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your help! It means a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`*list2 = list` is changing **the value of the data** the pointer `list2` is pointed to. The operator `*` preceding a pointer will refer to the data at the address stored in the pointer (known as [dereferencing](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)).

Basically `list2` is a pointer that stores an address that points in memory to where `list` is (this happened when you wrote `list2 = &list`). You use `*list2` to go to **the data stored** at the address and change it to `list` when you have the declare `*list2 = list;`.

Comment: But if `list2 = &list`, doesn't that make the operation `*&list = list;` or just `list = list;`?

Comment: Yes it is essentially the same, as @JaMiT referred to in his answer